# PNP: What happens if the base voltage is higher than the emitter voltage?

Tags: bjt, switching, pnp, bias

Can a PNP transistor switch a 5 volt load such that in the off state the base is supplied with 12 volts and the on state is pulled to ground (Vb > Ve)?

I remember hearing that the base voltage needs to be lower than the emitter voltage, but I do not remember why or what the side effect might be. I think this is just a reverse bias and as long as the reverse bias voltage is below the breakdown voltage then it should work, but please fill in any information that I might be missing here, or best practices that should be considered.

[image: Dual-voltage PNP switch]

https://crcit.net/c/a9e88922bcae40ce8d8a41e197bc3603

We need to power a 5v LNA at the end of a bias tee when the radio isn't transmitting.  It emits 13.8V out the control line while idle, hence PNP. The 100-ohm load in the circuit is the LNA.

Comment: I didn't look at the link, yet. Just wanted to say that if the base voltage of a small signal PNP BJT is sufficiently reverse-biased, it will break down. For common PNPs this may be at about 5, 6, or 7 volts, roughly. If you need some kind of fuller answer and explain better, I might try an answer. Otherwise, that's all you need to know I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum reverse bias on the base-emitter junction is around 6 V for many small signal transistors. You could damage the transistor which may not be obvious at first. Over time, the transistor could become noisier if an over-voltage condition exists at the B-E junction.

A fun thing happens with B-E breakdown, the junction emits light.

[Edit]
Just for fun I cut apart a 2N2222 transistor and took a picture of the glowing reverse biased junction. The breakdown voltage is 7.0 V and current set to 8.8 mA. Barely visible with the naked eye.

[image]
right image: ISO=800, f/5.0, 1/25 sec shutter speed
Photo credits: own work

Comment: So would a simple voltage divider solve the breakdown issue?

Comment: @KJ7LNW A voltage divider will work. If you don't mind the added current draw, a diode across the base-emitter leads will limit the B-E voltage to 0.7 V. Why not use a NPN transistor?

Comment: Wow, neat photo effect!  FYI, I updated the question regards to needing PNP vs NPN.  Basically we need to switch 5v power when the base is given 12v (but we'll use a voltage divider) to power an LNA.

Comment: The LNA is my son's project, here is a video about it: https://youtu.be/dH7OX47ICmY

Comment: @KJ7LNW Great to get your kid interested in electronics, RF at that! I would put the LNA between ground and the collector. You may have unintended ground paths from the RF connections which will keep the LNA on all the time in the configuration you show.